# bash script runs perfectly when started manually - but not when started in reboot mode

Tags: bash, tail

I have this bash script which runs automatically at reboot.

**run.sh**

```
printf "Running log registration\n"


printf "Running log registration\n"
printf 'try1 ' > /home/pi/Desktop/system_logs/msg_log.log

tail -f /var/log/messages &>> /home/pi/Desktop/system_logs/msg_log.log
```

It creates the file msg.log.log
and write "try 1"
BUT it doesn't write all the logs to the file

If I run the bash Script from the command line `bash run.sh`
then it also writing the logs
any sugestation  why the logs aren't written to file in the rebooting proccess?

Comment: How are you calling the script to run at startup? Via systemd? Via cronjob?

Comment: I run it on raspberry pi via rc.local. but I figured it out I miss placed the & operator it should be on the and of the line.Thanks a lot.